# blazor wasm + oauth + api =same token for api?

Tags: api, authentication, jwt, blazor

Im building some blazor wasm ,
i have oauth service in corporate network that i use for login i recive some token with payload of the user data and now question is should i use same token i recived to call my internal api for wasm client ?
how should i configure it?

i have now

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication((options) =>
{
options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "JwtBearer";
options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "JwtBearer";
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
 options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
  ValidateAudience = false,
  ValidateIssuer = false,
  ValidateLifetime = true,
  ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,       
};
});
```

but it returns me 401 - invalid key - why? should i do this this way ? or it is bad approach ? if so What is good ? for external oauth + blazor wasm + server api ?
if im validating only lifetime then why it is 401?
thanks and regards

Comment: What if you need to add additional claims or roles ?

Comment: im getting all claims/roles in this token from oauth service already from also some corporate ssytem that holds users permissions to many applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In client:

```
public class CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler:AuthorizationMessageHandler
{
    public CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler(IAccessTokenProvider provider, NavigationManager nav) : base(provider, nav)
    {
        ConfigureHandler(authorizedUrls: new[] { nav.BaseUri });
    }
}
```

In program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IHttpService, HttpService>((serviceProvider, client) => {
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);  
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>() ;
```

And in API's program.cs:

```
builder.Services
.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
.AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://SAMEasOauthInClient";
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = false;
});
```

And this works.